# How to inline CSS for sub-components of JavaFX Control

Tags: css, javafx, checkbox

Given I have added the class style 'checkless-checkbox' to my CheckBox, I can then specify the following CSS code within a CSS file, to effectively hide the Box and Mark sub-components of the JavaFX CheckBox.

```
     .checkless-checkbox>.box { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
     .checkless-checkbox:selected>.box>.mark{ -fx-background-color:transparent; }
```

Can I, and if so how, specify the CSS styles for .box and :selected>.box>.mark sub-components programmatically from my Java code rather than having to add a CSS file?

Comment: This is only a possibility for colors and it only works, if the user agent stylesheet (should be `modena.css`) uses lookedup colors. Unless you're lucky, there may be more colors that are changed by modifying the base lookedup color on the parent...

Comment: Dear @fabien many thanks, but I do not understand your comment (my lack of understanding I'm sure), but the technique I am using with an external CSS file allows me to set style for the sub components .box and .mark of the Cherckbox control, I just want to be avle to achieve the same directly from my Java code but I cannot see how to access the .box and .mark sub components of the CheckBox control from Java - any suggestions?

Comment: I'm referring to the *lookedup-colors* section in [the CSS Reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor). The user agent stylesheet responsible for the default style makes extensive use of this. In `modena.css` the rule to color the background looks like this: `-fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;` note the use of the lookedup colors `-fx-mark-highlight-color` and `-fx-mark-color`. Those you can set via inline style for the `CheckBox`.

Comment: If one of those is used to e.g. choose the color of other parts of the `CheckBox` that should keep their color, you cannot apply this approach. You cannot include selectors in inline style...